# Как в Handlebars реализовать такие условия?

Tags: handlebars

Я вывожу такие данные и таким образом:

```
{{regular}}
```

regular = 21.5,
Но мне нужно сопоставить эти данные, условно если regular = 21.5, тогда я должен вывести строку "5/2", так же если regular = 15 тогда "2/2", таких вариаций около 7 штук.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос. Вам интересна реализация условий в handlebars или форматирование значений?

Comment: @IvanPivkin формирование значений

Answer (score 0):

Используйте промежуточное ПО самого handlebars:

```
/***    Set up handlebars view engine    ***/
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  helpers: {
    section: function(name, options) {
      if (!this._sections) this._sections = {};
      this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
      return null;
    },

    ...

    lookupCategories: (prop) => {
      let out = "";
      for(let i in prop[0]) {
        out += '<th>';
        out += `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="${i}" disabled>`;
        out += `</th>`;
      }
      return out;
    }
  }
});
```

Самое необходимое здесь, в моем случае, это lookupCategories. 
Переписываете его как вам нужно, переименовываете как желаете и используете.
Пример использования:

```
{{#lookupCategories category}}

{{/lookupCategories}}
```

Откуда береться category?
Из аргумента, переданного в res.render:

```
res.render('showApartments', {apart: context.apart, category: context.apart} );
```

Исходник данного кода: https://github.com/MiMEKiZ/laba2ExpertRating